# react-id-swiper navigation arrow buttons and pagination not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, swiper.js

I am trying to use **react-id-swiper** in my project. I am just following the examples as shown in this website: https://react-id-swiper.ashernguyen.site/example/navigation.

For some reason the navigation buttons (Left and Right navigation arrow buttons) are not working for me. I even tried using the pagination, even that doesn't work.

This is the codesandbox that I created: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-leftpad-9cgts?file=/src/App.js

Here's the code that I am using:

```
    import React from "react";
    import Swiper from "react-id-swiper";
    
    import "swiper/swiper.scss";
    import "swiper/components/navigation/navigation.scss";
    import "swiper/components/pagination/pagination.scss";
    import "./styles.scss";
    
    const params = {
      effect: "cube",
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
      }
    };
    
    const Slider = () => {
      return (
        <Swiper {...params}>
          <div className="myslide">Slide #1</div>
          <div className="myslide">Slide #2</div>
          <div className="myslide">Slide #3</div>
          <div className="myslide">Slide #4</div>
          <div className="myslide">Slide #5</div>
        </Swiper>
      );
    };
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Slider />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

I have the code examples taken from here: https://react-id-swiper.ashernguyen.site/example/navigation .
Can someone tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution of this issue,
the root cause are:

1. the version of react-id-swiper and swiper did not match each other
   I fix this by using react-id-swiper@4.0.0 and swiper@6.0.4
2. need to import below packages

```
import Swiper from 'react-id-swiper';
import SwiperCore, { Pagination } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
```

and add this use code after import

```
SwiperCore.use([Pagination]);
```

I got the answer from here: https://github.com/kidjp85/react-id-swiper/issues/453#issuecomment-814500317

Hope this answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue.

The reason is that `swiper@^6.4.5` is used. I don't know since what version exactly, but in `6.4.5` swiper has its own implementation of react components, which we have to use.

Refer to this page to understand how to use swiper's react implementation:
https://swiperjs.com/react/

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue as well. Even after you import it you have to load the modules directly onto the component.

Follow the code below and it should work perfectly

```
    import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
    import "swiper/css/pagination"; // if yo want to style it 
    import { Navigation, Pagination} from "swiper";

const Slider = () => {
      return (
         <Swiper 
     modules={[Pagination]}//you can add any other module here such as navigation and whatever else 
pagination={{ clickable: true }}
>
              <div className="myslide">Slide #1</div>
              <div className="myslide">Slide #2</div>
              <div className="myslide">Slide #3</div>
              <div className="myslide">Slide #4</div>
              <div className="myslide">Slide #5</div>
            </Swiper>
          );
        };
```